# How to set application insights SDK proxy configuration?

Tags: proxy, azure-application-insights

I’ve built a .NET Windows Service that keeps monitoring the DB latency from a Web Server. Every time the test runs it sends a Metric to App Insights via the SDK. On my development machine all works fine, but when it’s deployed to the webserver the metrics doesn’t reach the App Insights service because a proxy authentication failure occurs. This is the error that I’ve found by analyzing the network activity:

**Proxy Authentication Required. Authentication Failure.Please check your username and password.**

How can I set the proxy settings for App Insights for my Windows Service? Is there something similar to the “*ApplicationInsights.config*” file of web sites?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I figure it out. What I was missing is setting the proxy on the app.config file adding:

```
<system.net> 
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" /> 
</system.net>
```